# 20-hr layover in Japan

Tags: transit, japan, covid-19, layovers, nrt

I am traveling from Hawaii, back to Indonesia. Is it possible to stay in the hotel around Narita airport during 20 hours layover, to catch up the next plane?

Comment: Which airlines are you flying on, and do you have a single ticket covering the entire trip?

Answer (score 8):

In normal times yes, but due to COVID Japan remains essentially closed at this time, with **only Japanese citizens and close relatives allowed to enter**.  So I'm afraid you'll be stuck in the airport.

Narita does have [day use hotel rooms](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/connect/inter/), but it is *not* a 24-hour airport, so I'm actually not entirely sure your connection is legal.  I would suggest you double-check with the airline.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information.

Comment: Day rooms are until 22:00, so I'm afraid overnight stays are not permitted. Also, maybe also check with the airline.